# Why is 'CustomerOrOrganizationInNoUpdateDocRestrictor' inaccessible in my Acumatica project?

Tags: acumatica

Good morning!  I have a customer ID field included in the table DAC.  I would like for this selector to operate identically to the customer ID field in the sales order form.  I used all pertinent DAC code from the sales order to create the field in my custom screen; however, when I attempt to use all the same attributes for the restrictor, the following attribute cannot be accessed.  I have all the appropriate references included in the project(PX.Objects.AR).  Any assistance or work around for this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

```
#region CustomerID
        public abstract class customerID : BqlInt.Field<customerID>
        {
            public class PreventEditBAccountCOrgBAccountID<TGraph> :
                PreventEditBAccountRestrictToBase<BAccount.cOrgBAccountID, TGraph, NXBOL,
                    SelectFrom<NXBOL>
                    .Where<NXBOL.bolType.IsNotEqual<NXBOLType.nonProductMovement>.
                        And<NXBOL.customerID.IsEqual<BAccount.bAccountID.FromCurrent>>>>
                where TGraph : PXGraph
            {
                protected override string GetErrorMessage(BAccount baccount, NXBOL document, string documentBaseCurrency)
                {
                    return PXMessages.LocalizeFormatNoPrefix(Messages.CannotChangeRestricToIfShipmentExists,
                        documentBaseCurrency, baccount.AcctCD, document.BOLNbr);
                }
            }

            public class PreventEditBAccountCOrgBAccountIDOnVendorMaint : PreventEditBAccountCOrgBAccountID<VendorMaint>
            {
                public static bool IsActive()
                    => PXAccess.FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.multipleBaseCurrencies>();
            }

            public class PreventEditBAccountCOrgBAccountIDOnCustomerMaint : PreventEditBAccountCOrgBAccountID<CustomerMaint>
            {
                public static bool IsActive()
                    => PXAccess.FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.multipleBaseCurrencies>();
            }
        }
        protected Int32? _CustomerID;
        [CustomerActive(
            typeof(Search<BAccountR.bAccountID, Where<True, Equal<True>>>), // TODO: remove fake Where after AC-101187
            Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, Required = true)]
        [CustomerOrOrganizationInNoUpdateDocRestrictor]
        [PXForeignReference(typeof(Field<NXBOL.customerID>.IsRelatedTo<BAccount.bAccountID>))]
        public virtual Int32? CustomerID
        {
            get
            {
                return this._CustomerID;
            }
            set
            {
                this._CustomerID = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

It appears that the [CustomerOrOrganizationInNoUpdateDocRestrictor] is not accessible.  The project will not build and receive the following error:

Error   CS0122  'CustomerOrOrganizationInNoUpdateDocRestrictor' is inaccessible due to its protection level

I have tried manipulating references, I would expect the attribute which is defined in PX.Objects.AR to work the same in my project as the PX.Objects.SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CustomerOrOrganizationInNoUpdateDocRestrictor is an internal class, so you can't access it.

You can use this restrictor instead:

```
[PXRestrictor(
        typeof(Where<Customer.type, IsNotNull, Or<Current<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder.aRDocType>,
            Equal<ARDocType.noUpdate>, And<Current<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder.behavior>, Equal<SOBehavior.tR>,
                And<Where<BAccountR.type, In3<BAccountType.branchType, BAccountType.organizationType>,
                    Or<PX.Objects.CR.BAccount.isBranch, Equal<True>>>>>>>),
        "Only a customer or company business account can be specified.")]
```